# Android: PopupWindow Animation - Need to know when the animation has ended

Tags: android, animation, listener, popupwindow

I've got a `PopupWindow` that's using an alpha animation to produce a fade-in display of the window.

Using `PopupWindow.setAnimationStyle()` works as expected: the popup fades-in when shown.

However, once the popup is displayed (meaning the fade-in animation has completed) I'd like to kick off another animation.

I've tried using the following to obtain the underlying animation that's referred to via `setAnimationStyle()` and attach an `AnimationListener` to it:

```
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.popup_fade_in);
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fade-in animation START");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fade-in animation END");
        // Kick off the next animation
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
```

This does't work: None of the `AnimationListener` methods ever get called.

Anyone know of a way to determine when a popup window's animation has ended?

Alternatively, if there's a way to determine when the popup window has initially become visible I could kick off the secondary animation at that time. Unfortunately, I'm not finding anything in the API docs indicating how to do this.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(...) is inflating a new instance of the animation. Can you show us how you set the animation on the PopupWindow itself?

How are you showing the PopupWindow? Are you using something other than PopupWindow#show*(...)?

Comment: do you start animation at all? The following might be interesting to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221175/aos-4-x-issue-with-animation